# Format a large list of words to alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, replace, constants, alphanumeric

With regex I created a large list of PHP define from xml data list, here's an excerpt:

```
<?php
...
define("New Research ? (U)(GAI)",183);
define("Port, (GAI)",184);
define("Cathedral (U)(GAI)",185);
define("Civ: Indians (H)",186);
define("Bonus Heal +10% (A)",187);
define("Bombard Cannon (A)",188);
...
?>
```

So I have ~1000 defines like this, and as you see they are not valid. I need to replace all special caracters with "_" and uppercase letters.

I could use regex but it will be very laborious, there are too much cases to handle in this list, and I have to prevent getting double underscores like "__". More, I may do it again in future.

Do you have any idea of best way to fix this ? Is there an online tool to format any strings to correct alphanumeric format ?

Comment: Why would you want that as constants anyway? Wouldn't an *array* associating ids to titles make more sense?

Comment: 1) Why? 2) Have you tried something ?

Comment: because my IDE hasn't intelligent code completion for array keys. I need it to find what I need in a list of ~1000 words.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think to the exclusive regex showed in the other question !

Comment: Don't post answers in your question